# Centering Div with CSS

Tags: jquery, css, center

I have a div, and I want to center it. This works fine: `.div{ position: relative; width: 300px; margin: 0 auto;}`. Problem is that I need to get the height of the div, using jQuery `$('div').height()` However, this returns 0, but if I add `float: left` to the div, then jQuery works, but the div is no longer centered.

What can I do?

Thanks

Comment: You should get height even without `float: left` http://jsfiddle.net/z2CVW/3/. Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: try adding overflow: auto; to the div. This might not be the solution, since there aren't much details in your question, but trying wont hurt :P

Comment: What tag does .div belong to? Or should it be div?

Comment: Also, if .div is not a div, then $('div').height() does not make sense. And if div has no content and no css height set, then .height() will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont have content inside the div it will return **zero** unless you specify a static height/ min-height to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/NySST/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you can put exact width and height of the div it's easy to center with out using jquery.

or you may try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).resize(function(){

        $('#your-div-id').css({
            position:'absolute',
            left: ($(window).width() - $('#your-div-id').outerWidth())/2,
            top: ($(window).height() - $('#your-div-id').outerHeight())/2
        });

    });
    // To initially run the function:
    $(window).resize();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there *is* content within your `<div>`, you probably aren't clearing the floats for your inner elements properly. Try adding `overflow: hidden` to your `<div>` and see if that solves the problem.

A quick way to see if you're clearing your floats properly is to give your `<div>` an arbitrary background color such as `background: red`, which will show you how it wraps the content, if at all. See http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/PUETN/ for an example of what I'm talking about. *Note that the height of the red background represents the height of the containing `<div>`.*

Answer (score -2):

if your div has a defined width you can try setting the style  margin-left; auto; margin-right:auto;

Comment: And how does this solve his problem when he's already doing that?